How to link or associate the certificate in apple keychian with associated private key generated in secure enclave?
I have generated the keypair using secure enclave with (SecKeyCreateRandomKey()) , then created csr and then certificate is issued by CA. I have stored the certificate in keychain with (SecItemAdd()). Now i have to link this certificate with associated private key. I need the keychain access app to show certificate and key in the dropdown. How this can be achieved?
i tried SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate() but it didn't work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
